# ProcessBuilder doesn't use path environment

Tags: java, npm, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, processbuilder

My Jenkins pipeline starts a java program on ec2 machine. In this program, I try to call **npm install** using **ProcessBuilder** like below.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","-c", command)
Map<String, String> env = processBuilder.environment()
env.put("PATH", envPath)
```

envPath is my npm directory in **/home/.../bin** and command is **NPM INSTALL**. It runs in local machine without error.
But when program called via pipeline on ec2, it gives **/bin/bash: npm: command not found** error.

some details from ProcessBuilder.environment() at the runtime:

```
[PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.11.0/bin, USER:jenkins
```

What is wrong in here?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Why are you calling bash?  Why not just `new ProcessBuilder("npm", "install")`?  A new shell might or might not set its own path.